# Mysql two join on one table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables: matches, teams

In table matches I have home_id and away_id
I need to get 2 times the name of teams which are in table teams, but how?

I try this:
Select * from matches as m Inner join teams as t On m.home_id=t.team_id Inner join teams as ta On m.away_id
But in php (browser) isnt two teams, display only away team

... Also in phpmyadmin I get all what i need, how can get it into my app? :)

Comment: Hint:  `JOIN`.  Twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your select * should be something like m.*, t.teamname as "home team" ,ta.teamname as "away team"

Answer (score 0):

In PHP you are getting two of the same key "team_name" from both joins so you can rename them as I have here, home_team and away_team so you can access them in PHP properly.

`SELECT m_id, home_id, away_id, t.team_name as home_team, ta.team_name as away_team from matches as m
    inner join teams as t on m.home_id = t.team_id 
    inner join teams as ta on m.away_id = ta.team_id`